# Memory leak when using UITableView dequeueReusableCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, memory-leaks, swift4

I've checked my app for memory leaks in the instruments "Leaks" tool
and found about 16 of them on the controller that responsible for the UITableView content.

this is the code -

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "clause", for: indexPath) as! CodeOfConductTableViewCell

    cell.index.text = String(indexPath.row + 1)
    cell.cocTxt.text = lines["line\(indexPath.row + 1)"]

    return cell
}
```

[image]

when i changed the code to this:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = CodeOfConductTableViewCell()

    cell.index = UILabel()
    cell.cocTxt = UITextView()

    cell.index?.text = String(indexPath.row + 1)
    cell.cocTxt?.text = lines["line\(indexPath.row + 1)"]

    return cell
}
```

no leaks where detected.

what is causing the leaks? am i using it wrong?

I want to use this function since it's better for performance,
and i want to understand what's wrong here

Thanks!

EDIT:

adding cell class code (nothing fancy here):

```
class CodeOfConductTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var index: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cocTxt: UITextView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "better for performance"?

Comment: How are you creating the label and text view in your cell in the first example? Are the variables declared as weak?

Comment: @skladek yes, they are declared as weak outlets. no special initialization..

Comment: @ChipCoons instead of creating new cells, this function reuse the cells that are offscreen. if i have a very big table, the app will run out of memory if i'll keep creating new cells.

Comment: what does lines contain?

Comment: @nikBhosale lines is a dictionary parsed from a json file. that contains couple of lines of text...

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your string literal ("clause") in the method call totableView.dequeueReusableCell.

From the apple documents on strings:

> You can create new strings using string literals or string
>   interpolations. A string literal is a series of characters enclosed in
>   quotes.

And

> Although strings in Swift have value semantics, strings use a
>   copy-on-write strategy to store their data in a buffer. This buffer
>   can then be shared by different copies of a string. A string’s data is
>   only copied lazily, upon mutation, when more than one string instance
>   is using the same buffer.

I believe you are allocating 48 bytes each time the method is called with the creation of a string literal.  I would think the compiler should optimize this away, but am not certain.

If your CodeOfConductTableViewCell() initializer is loading the resource from Xcode, it would have the overhead of reading the xib, which may explain the performance differences you are seeing.

You should make your identifier a constant in the module and see if the leak goes away, since the compiler will only allocate it once then.

Comment: i made "clause" a static string. still leaks...  :(

Comment: I created a simple test project with a UITableView and a close approximation of your code (obviously it does not have a CodeOfConductTableViewCell object), and could not create a leak condition.  I suspect there is something in your view cell class that is the source of the leak.

Comment: i will test it latter, but shouldn't i get leaks with my changed code example as well? (where i'm creating CodeOfConductTableViewCell explicitly)

Comment: i've stripped it down to only return the dequeued cell without assigning any data. still leaks  :(
i've added the cell class code to the question above. only two outlets.
i'm losing it man.....

Comment: Do you have a test data set for lines?  Re-creating your code without that one line also runs with no leak.  (i.e. commented out the cell.cocTxt.text = lines["line\(indexPath.row + 1)"] line)

Comment: i commented out that line. still leaks.. only when replacing the "dequeueReusableCell" with creating my own cells - no leaks.